# Test clone SharePoint and Project Server2010

Tags: migration, sql, sharepont

I am new to this SharePoint and Project server. I have joined an organisation and my luck the Sharepoint guy has left. Now I have to handle these servers and have to migrate them to newer version.

For couple of days I have been studying on SharePoint and Project server and got to much about it.
In current scenario there are three servers:

- SQL 2008 R2 server
- Domain Server
- SharePoint 2010 and Project Server 2010 combined.

Now I require help if any one can guide for the following:

1. As I have to create a test environment by cloning the above servers in my organisation, can i do it directly through database backup only (without taking any farm backup)
2. As I will install test environment, the IP, server name and admin accounts would be different, would that affect the database and what changes would I need to do in order to make the installations work.
3. If I create new sites in SharePoint and project server, then will the data restore from the database?

If anyone has any video links for this then it will be really easy to follow step by step installation and also steps to migrate to SQL 2012 and SharePoint and PS 2013 in later stage.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the backup and restore, you have to install all custom Solutions on the new Server which are installed on the old server, before restore.

Also old and new Server should have the same patch Level.

If you do a backup, restore and reattachment, the Content is naturally the same like the site when you did the backup. It contains all the sites, web and data of the Content database.

If you use managed metadata, also make sure to migrate the Database of it.